# Loop Until Two Numbers Don't Match

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to set a textbox.value to a random number and loop until it gets to a number not equal to another textbox value.  I'm getting an infinite loop though. I'm probably missing something pretty fundamental here...

```
me.Text1.Value = 1
me.Text2.Value = 5
rndPlace = Int((5 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)

Do

me.Text1.Value = rndPlace

Loop Until me.Text1.Value <> me.Text2.Value
```

Comment: Since `Text1.Value = 1` and `TextBox2.Value = 5`, why would the loop ever need to run? The exit condition (`Text1.Value <> Text2.Value`) already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
me.Text1.Value = 1
me.Text2.Value = 5


Do
    rndPlace = Int((5 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    me.Text1.Value = rndPlace

Loop Until me.Text1.Value <> me.Text2.Value
```

`rndPlace = Int((5 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)` needs to be in the body of the loop. Otherwise, when you enter the loop with `rndPlace = 5` you will never leave it.

Comment: Long day, that makes perfect sense.  I can't believe I missed that.